# Send data from component to Vuex

Tags: vuex, dispatch, payload

I have a component file in which I send id using `dispatch`:

```
mounted() {
    const warehouseId = this.$route.params.id;
    this.$store.dispatch("showWarehouse", {warehouseId}).then(() => {
        this.warehouseData = this.$store.state.showWarehouses;
    });
},
```

I get `id` of element from route (`warehouseId`), next I run action `showWarehouse`.
In store.js (Vuex) file I have an action:

```
showWarehouse({ commit }, payload) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axios.get('/api/warehouse/' + payload)
            .then(response => {
                commit('showWarehouse', response.data);
                resolve();
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.warn(error);
            });
    });
}
```

I try get `id` from componnt using `payload`, but probably this value is `undefined`. When I change:

```
axios.get('/api/warehouse/' + payload)
```

to

```
axios.get('/api/warehouse/1')
```

`axios` return correctly data from database.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a solution

I must just add `payload.warehouseId`:

```
axios.get('/api/warehouse/' + payload.warehouseId)
```

`warehouseId` must been this the same name from a component:

```
this.$store.dispatch("showWarehouse", {warehouseId})
```